# Why mutual inductance between two coil having $n$ numbers of turns per unit length in one coil is given by below formula?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Considee there is magnetic field generated by a solenoid having n number of turns per unit length , using that for calculating flux in a small conducting ring placed at centre of it the magnetic flux turns out to be u_°nI *area, my question is then why when calcuating mutual inductance is that the M = N(flux), why not just n(flux)=M? as such we considered just a surface and there only n number of turns per unit length are there so why its written always as $N$ not $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flux density is proportional to $n$, the number of turns per unit length of solenoid. [$n=N/l$ in which $N$ is simply the number of turns on the solenoid and $l$ is its length.] The reason for this can be seen when we use the Biot-Savart law to derive the equation
$$B=\mu_0 n I =\frac{\mu_0 N I}l.$$

We now place another coil (say with $N'$ turns and area $A'$ inside the solenoid and co-axial with it. The magnetic flux, $\Phi$ through each turn of this coil will be
$$\Phi = BA' = \mu_0 n A'I =\frac{\mu_0 N A'I}l.$$

When the current changes in the solenoid, an emf $\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$ will be induced in each turn of the secondary coil, but the turns are in series, so the total emf will be
$$\mathscr E= N'\frac{d\Phi}{dt}=\frac{d(N'\Phi)}{dt}$$

Note the last step: including the $N'$ in the differentiand. That's the motivation for calculating the *flux linkage* with the secondary coil, namely
$$N'\Phi = N'BA' = \mu_0nN' A'I =\frac{\mu_0 N N'A'I}l.$$

Comment: Sir i think i got it now : flux linkage would be due to all loops . I initially thought that flux is basically field lines from a **surface ** which means that is N'/L as its giving per unit surface how many turns are there , but as emf is due to sum of all turns total hence that am i right Sir?

Comment: I'm afraid I find this hard to follow. (a) I'd say that flux can be represented as filed lines *through* a surface (not *from* a surface). (b) "which means that is N'/l as its giving per unit surface how many turns are there" I think you're on the wrong track here. If you know the Biot-Savart law, you should look up the derivation of $B=\mu_0 n I$ for a solenoid. Then you'll see why $n=N/L$ features in the formula.

Comment: Hmm Sir i understood just one more thing : flux linkage in secondary coil is phi itself , but when we are calculating emf induced we would need all contribution of flux though all turns hence Nphi right ?

Comment: You can either calculate $\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$ for a single turn, then multiply that emf by $N'$ as the turns are in series **or** – and this is the motivation for mutual inductance – we can multiply the flux through a single turn by the number of turns (getting $N'\Phi$) and differentiate *that* with respect to $t$. It gives the same result.

Comment: Understood Sir thanks